# How to read details of event SELECT_CONTENT in Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase

I use Firebase Analytics and send custom events with this code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "value");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "value");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "event");              
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

I see my events in Firebase Console. They are looking like clickable elements but when I try to click on them nothing happened.
The code was not changed, it worked fine some time ago but it does not work now.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a known issue as Firebase Support says. No changes needed from my side. We can only watch on the Firebase releases and wait while it will be resolved: https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Comment: Please do you have a link to the page / ticket saying it's an issue?